# How to load values from file to mysql, where in (file)

Tags: mysql, file, where-clause

I need to make select where id in ( and here i want to load text file, with one int value per one line)

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Does your input file have a header line, or does the first line contain data?

Comment: first line contains data

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use temporary table

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `temp` (`id` bigint(20) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(`id`))
```

then load data from file using

```
LOAD DATA INFILE ...
```

and then select your data using temporary table

```
SELECT * FROM some_table s, temp t WHERE s.id = t.id
```

Answer (score 2):

Because your input text file has only one int value per line, you should be able to get away with this:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'input.txt' INTO TABLE yourTable
```

Comment: but i dont want to insert values into table, i need to make query like this:
select * from users where id in (file with int values)

Comment: MySQL doesn't operate this way.  If the data be located in a file, you should first load it into a table.  Afterwards, you can query as you want.